# Understanding the following definition of torsion free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

So I'm having some trouble seeing why the following is true immediately. So according to wikipedia;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_module.

The first paragraph reads:

"In integral domains the regular elements of the ring are its nonzero elements, so in this case a torsion-free module is one such that zero is the only element annihilated by some non-zero element of the ring. Some authors work only over integral domains and use this condition as the definition of a torsion-free module, but this does not work well over more general rings, for if the ring contains zero-divisors then the only module satisfying this condition is the zero module"

I'm definitely missing something trivially obvious; but I cant see immediately why having a zero-divisor immediately leads to the conclusion that the module **MUST** be the zero module ?

Any help or insights is appreciated.
Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ has a zero divisor $a$ (so that $ba = 0$ for some nonzero $b$) and $M$ is an $A$-module. If $M \neq 0$ then let $m \in M$ be nonzero. Then it is the case that $am = 0$ or we have $am \neq 0$ and $b(am) = 0$ - in both cases something non-zero is killed by a nonzero element of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be an $M$-module and suppose $R$ is not an integral domain so $ab = 0$ for some $a,b \in R\setminus\{0\}$. Let $m \in M \setminus\{0\}$.

If $bm = 0$ we are done. Otherwise, $a(bm) = (ab)m = 0 m = 0$ so it is not torsion free. Hence, the only torsion free module over $R$ would be $0$.